# Different data on internationalization

Tags: django, internationalization, django-rest-framework

The endpoint called in the default language (English) works fine, but in arabic I get values as None.

Here's the code

serializers.py

```
def validate(self, validated_data):
    support_request = validated_data.get('support_request')
    amount = validated_data.get('amount')

    if support_request.raised_in_full():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Targeted amount already received'))

    if amount > support_request.remaining_amount:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            _('You cannot support with more than {} KWD'.format(support_request.remaining_amount)))
    return validated_data
```

models.py

```
class SupportRequest(TimeStampedModel):
    @property
    def amount(self):
        try:
            value = self.form_values.filter(field__label=self.amount_field.label).first().value
            value = Decimal(value).quantize(THREEDIGITS)
        except:
            value = None
        return value

    @property
    def remaining_amount(self):
        if all([self.raised, self.amount]):
            return self.amount - self.raised
       return self.amount


    def raised_in_full(self):
        if self.amount == self.raised:
            return True
        return False
```

The endpoint works perfectly on english, but on arabic it fails.
I've logged all variables and for english all of them has values, in Arabic doesn't.

It's tested with Postman and rest framework form interface.

validated_data looks the same on both languages.

```
amount is ok
support_request.amount None
support_request.raised is ok
support_request.remaining_amount is None
```

I don't understand how internationalization can cause this.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've logged all variables and for english all of them has values, in Arabic doesn't"? The only thing that should be different here is the string used for the error messages.

Comment: It was my fault, actually the form_values were also translated with django-modeltranslation and the string used to query the db was also arabic, because the getter returns the internationalized value, but on query looks in english column. I've fixed it easily by appending _en to self.amount_field.label. :)